# Swift Vapor project not compiling due to strange errors in swift-nio

Tags: swift, vapor

I can't get my Swift Vapor project to compile (which was running fine before), because *nio* produces strange errors all of a sudden:

[image]

Also, `swift package update` produces this:

```
.build/checkouts/swift-nio: error: Couldn’t check out revision ‘546610d52b19be3e19935e0880bb06b9c03f5cef’
```

I already cleaned, deleted derived data and rebuilt....any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides cleaning & re-building the project, you can try deleting the following files / directories:

- `/.build`
- `/.swiftpm`
- `/Package.resolved`

Then, run `swift package update` and try to build the project again.